# Define Cursor with Dynamic Table Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT ORDER_ID
    FROM @TableName1

OPEN cursor1
FETCH next FROM cursor1 INTO @ORDER_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Hi'

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @ORDER_ID
END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

How to use dynamic table name in `SELECT` query to define cursor?

`@TableName1` is a `VARCHAR` variable which stores a table name.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ? There is probably other way of getting what you want without cursor

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the records of interest into a table variable / temporary table and then declare the cursor over that table:

```
declare @t table (
    OrderId int
);

declare @OrderId int, @Sql nvarchar(max);

set @Sql = N'select ORDER_ID from ' + @TableName1;

insert into @t (OrderId)
exec (@Sql);

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR LOCAL fast_forward FOR
SELECT OrderId from @t;

OPEN cursor1;

WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @ORDER_ID;

    if @@fetch_status != 0
        break;

    PRINT 'Hi';
END

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @TableName1 as varchar(256)
set @TableName1 = 'TableName'

declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR GLOBAL FOR SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ' + cast(@TableName1 as nvarchar(256))
exec(@sql)

OPEN cursor1
FETCH next FROM cursor1 INTO @ORDER_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ORDER_ID=' + cast(@ORDER_ID as varchar(256))

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @ORDER_ID
END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

Comment: `exec()` run in separate context. The `LOCAL CURSOR` is not recognizalbe by `OPEN cursor` in the rest of the code. You need to use `CURSOR GLOBAL` for `exec()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a cursor to a dynamic/variable table by using sp_executesql and output-ing an open cursor. Cursor names can also be variable.

```
declare @TableName1 varchar(50) = 'TableName';
--declare @sql nvarchar(max)= concat('set @mycursor = cursor for select * from ', QUOTENAME(@TableName1), '; open @mycursor;');
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'set @dynamicsqlcursor = cursor for select name from sys.objects; open @dynamicsqlcursor;';

declare @mycursor cursor, 
        @objname sysname;

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @sql, @params = N'@dynamicsqlcursor cursor output', @dynamicsqlcursor = @mycursor output; --the output cursor must be open

--no need to open the cursor, it is output "opened"
--open @mycursor;

fetch next from @mycursor into @objname;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    print 'object name=' + @objname;

    fetch next from @mycursor into @objname;
end

close @mycursor;
deallocate @mycursor;
```